# Why don't women vote more for female candidates for office?

Tags: united-states, voting, gender, identity-politics

Women are at least 50% (give or take) of the electorate.

However, they clearly are a small fraction of elected politicians.

There are plenty of reasons why a woman may not want to **run** for office in the first place (your prefered reason may vary with your ideology).

However, what is puzzling, is why do women (or any other identity-politics aficionados who care more about gender than a person's individual qualities) who complain about lack of women being elected, don't actually put their money where their mouths are and support and vote for those women who DO run for office?

**This isn't even a partisan thing** - plenty of women vote for a man in Democratic primaries featuring both genders, where the standard idiotic explanation of "female candidate is a Republican woman and thus anti-women as all Republicans are" doesn't fly. Let's take the most high-profile case: 2008 Clinton/Obama primaries:

- Young women supported Obama by 53-45 percent on Super Tuesday ([src](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/behind-the-clinton-obama-draw/))
- Same Super Tuesday, general gender gap was mostly ~10% ([src](http://www.cawp.rutgers.edu/fast_facts/voters/documents/SuperTuesday_Clinton.pdf)); with NO STATE aside from Clinton's home Arkansas having >60% of women vote for her and many states <50% voted for her
- Another stats for the whole nomination in 2008: Hillary Clinton got only 51.5% total female votes vs. Obama's 48.5% ([src](http://anepigone.blogspot.com/2008/06/democratic-nomination-voter-totals-by.html))

Comment: This is only "puzzling" because its based on a faulty (and insulting) premise.  That a significant enough majority of all women "care more about gender than a person's individual qualities" and routinely vote accordingly is simply not supported by fact.  There certainly are such people, but not enough to ensure electoral landslides for female candidates.  If we view women as rational voters who likely weigh any number of different issues that they find important before making a decision on a slate of candidates, than this example is anything but puzzling.

Comment: @MichaelKingsmill the premise is the shrill yelling about "patriarchy" in connection with how many women are in elected positions, last heard this election day. What you proposed sounds like a plausible explanation *to me*, but should be backed up by surveys and such.

Comment: The title doesn't seem to match the question. Do we KNOW that women don't vote more for women when they are on the ballot? Or is the question why aren't there more women on the ballot to begin with? I think using only one example might not translate to the trend in general (it may, but hard to say).

Comment: As a male I can not answer this question. I can only speculate that an underlying cultural perception of politics as a "man's game" still exists. Much as mathematics and surgery used to be; and game programming is in the process of shifting on.

Comment: The inertia of the existing system may be an explanation. For instance, when initially there were few female surgeons, few people would have been comfortable in being under the knife with them; even if the size of their cohort had nothing rationally to do with their competency.

Comment: @LateralFractal - as a male (or a female, I have no idea who you are being on internet) you can most certainly read surveys :)

Comment: @DA. - the question has 3 sets of statistics with sources, for an election that had no partisan component. Can you explain how much more "knowing" do you expect me to put into the question? "why there aren't more women on the ballot" is explicitly **excluded** from the question in the last 5 words of 3rd paragraph.

Comment: @DVK Most of my tentacles reaching through a rift in the Outer Void self-identify as male.

Comment: @dvk if you're asking "Why didn't more women vote for Hilary in 2008?" then those examples are perfect. But I don't see them as proving anything in general. It very well *may be* indicative of the norm, but I don't know.

Comment: And from the first link you cite, there's excerpts such as "securing 65 percent of white female voters" which would seem to indicate that women *do* vote more for female candidates--again, if we're using just this one example.

Comment: @DA. - we are talking about a demographics that is nearly 100% VERY concerned with lack of female elected positions. . I would expect close to 100% votes for Hillary given that, not a spread between 35 and 60%. Remember, this is Dem primary - there aren't major policy positions differentiating them as they would be in general elections. And Hillary had no electability concerns either.

Comment: I think you're oversimplifying the voter thought process and focusing on merely one example.

Comment: *"This is only "puzzling" because its based on a faulty (and insulting) premise.  That a significant enough majority of all women "care more about gender than a person's individual qualities" and routinely vote accordingly is simply not supported by fact."* It is good to know that **feminist** politics is dead, and people don't buy into their faulty reasoning. Whoever said [facts stopped feminists](http://dontneedfeminism.com/post/84284636370/laci-green-50-reasons-for-being-a-feminist), "*Because the political body making decisions about my body is over 80% male…wow.*" --Laci Green

Comment: @user1873 a mens-rights blog is hardly a valid counter argument to Michael's point. In fact, bringing mens-rights arguments into this actually bolsters the point--there's a lot of wild assumptions out there as to what people (namely men) think women should be voting for.

Comment: @DA. - there is only ONE assumption being made here. That is that an accusation of "not enough women in office" means that those accusing have a priority of putting more women in office. Otherwise there wouldn't be a complaint from them.

Comment: @DA., the quote is from a self-identified **feminist**. Not sure exactly how you assumed this was an argument made by a MRA. Do they complain that Congress is 80% male?. She is the one assuming that more women should be voted into Congress/Senate. I don't claim that women should be voting for women, instead I argue that a persons sex has no bearing on the matter whether someone should be elected. So, if anyone is making assumptions here, it is feminists, who believe that sex is a valid reason to discriminate against someone.

Comment: It's because the subset of women who care so much about stopping the "patriarchy" that they would vote based on gender, are such a small subset among all women, that their voting bias is not enough to get Hilary Clinton elected over Obama

Comment: @SamIam - is there a poll to back up that quantitative assessment?

Comment: @DVK yeah, you included 3 of them in your question

Comment: @SamIam - Not voting for Hillary could have other causes/explanations.

Answer (score 13):

**Few voters are more/less likely to vote for a candidate because she is a women.**

A [recent pew poll](http://www.people-press.org/2014/05/19/for-2016-hopefuls-washington-experience-could-do-more-harm-than-good/) 71% of the public said it would not matter if a candidate for President was a woman.  The only traits with less impact on support for a candidate were whether the candidate was Hispanic, Catholic, in their 40s, or attended a prestigious university.

Other polls have similarly found a lack of bias against women candidates. A [Gallup poll found](http://www.gallup.com/poll/155285/atheists-muslims-bias-presidential-candidates.aspx) that if a well-qualified candidate happened to be a woman, 95% of those polled would vote for them. Only Blacks (96%) rated higher, and Atheists (54%), Muslims (58%), and Gays (68%) ranking at the bottom. Women ranked similarly regardless of the political affiliation of the person polled.

Pew also tested for [hidden gender bias](http://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2008/08/25/men-or-women-whos-the-better-leader/), often called the Bradley Effect or Wilder Effect. They had respondents rate hypothetical candidates that were identical, except for their gender. The results were clear, gender didn't matter. [Other studies](http://people.iq.harvard.edu/~dhopkins/wilder13.pdf) show a lack of hidden bias too, with female candidates for Senator out performing their poll numbers.

Your question is based on a faulty and insulting premise, that a significant majority of woman would care more about a candidates gender than their individual qualities. This might be [true](http://www.representation2020.com/) of [feminists](http://now.org/about/history/statement-of-purpose/), but isn't true of the vast majority as public polls have shown.